# Inducing $A_4$ from $\langle (123) \rangle$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

> Let $G=A_4$ and $H=\langle (123) \rangle < G$. Compute $Ind_{H}^G \chi$ for every irreducible $\chi$ of $H$.

Choose the right transversal of $H$ in $G$ as $V_4=\{ 1, (12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23) \}$. The conjugacy classes of $H$ are $\{1 \}$,$\{(123) \}$,$\{(132) \}$, of $A_4$ are $\{1 \}$,$C(123)$,$C(132)$ and $C((12)(34))$.

$\chi_1=(1,1,1),\chi_2=(1,\zeta,\zeta^2),\chi_3=(1,\zeta^2,\zeta)$.

Define $\psi=Ind \ \chi_i$ for $i=1,2,3$

Then apparently $$\psi((12)(34))= \chi_i^0((12)(34))+\dots+\chi_i^0((12)(34))=0$$
($V_4$ abelian)

I cannot see why this is.I thought $(12)(34)\in A_4$?  Why does it matter that $V_4$ is abelian?

Comment: I am afraid I cannot figure out exactly what you are asking. $\psi((12)(34)$ is the sum of $4$ terms, all of which are $0$, and it doesn't matter whether you take $i=1$, $2$ or $3$. The fact that your transversal $V_4$ is abelian and $(12)(34) \in V_4$ means that al four terms are the same. Yes, of course $(1,2)(3,4) \in A_4$

Comment: Thats answered it thanks